# react-datepicker value isn't changed when new date is selected

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a react datepicker (https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/)
When i change the date the value doesn't change to the date that i clicked.

I see this is a bug in the original component and i have reported it to the creator.

I was wondering if anyone has solved this problem before?

To see what i mean check take the following steps:

1. Go to http://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/
2. Inspect element on the date input field
3. Change the date with the pop-out box
4. Check the value of the inputbox again with inspect element. The value is still set to the date of today.

Hope someone has the answer for me!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the value of that field - you only need to be concerned about the component's state.value

When clicking a 'submit' button, you should be triggering a post of what's in the component's state.